# Smith Normal Form for PIDs

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, principal-ideal-domains, smith-normal-form

> Could someone provide a good reference to look up the existence and uniqueness of Smith Normal Form (SNF) for a PID?

I have seen it done for Euclidean domains but not for a PIDs. I know the difference is not much, but I would like a good reference. Thanks.

Comment: The 3 elementary row and column operations are not enough to obtain SNF over a PID.

Comment: What messi says. If $\gcd(a,b)=1$, then Bezout says that we can find $u,v$ such that $au-bv=1$, and we need to include 2-D transforms of the form $$\pmatrix{a&b\cr v&u\cr}$$ in the list of operations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See Hungerford, *Algebra*, 1974, Proposition 2.11, page 339.

Answer (score 4):

See Jacobson's *Basic Algebra I*, chapter 3.

See also the book *Finitely Generated Abelian Groups and Similarity of Matrices over a Field* by Christopher Norman.